# Access to data out of foreach knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have three similar foreaches, from them I choose items (chekboxes), these items are displayed in `data-bind="foreach: SelectedBooks"` `data-bind="text: bookName"`.

But, how I can get access to the choses items outside of the used `data-bind="foreach: AllBooks"` and display data in other place.

Something like this `data-bind="text: $root.userName, $root.bookName, $root.someName"` with saving of the order of the selected items?

I tried to use this documentations http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html but its still doesn't work.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/falkone/acdbrxy7/

Comment: The fiddle works, what is the problem? You want to (1) *combine* those arrays into one view? Or (2) display only the selected items in another view?

Comment: 2, display only the selected items in another view

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the knockout context debugger plugin for chrome, it's useful when it comes to debugging the mark up:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?hl=en